# Site JavaScript optimization with JavaScript compression

Tags: javascript, performance

- I have a site with many webparts created in visual studio, each webpart is referencing a JavaScript file, and I have some pages with 5 or 6 webparts.

  Whats the best practice to do compression for JavaScript files in this case? Is it going to be OK to reference each JavaScript for the webpart individually?
- In my master page, I have references to jQuery, jQueryUI, bootstrap.js and many other tools, what's the best to do in this case? do I compress all of them in one file? if yes, how to do it?

Thanks.